# facebook graph feed some fields by some users a missing

Tags: facebook-graph-api, field, feed

Very strange. I get a feed from a group with a valid token.
But from some users one or more fields are missing. Mostly the field "picture" but sometime also the field status.

In the normal view of the group everything is shown.

Is this a bug that some fields in the graph feed a missing? I can't explain that to myself.

Thanks for any help!